# Twitter widget code generated without an iframe

Tags: javascript, twitter

How to get the twitter widget code generated without an iframe so that I can override the css properties of my twitter widget from my applications css.
Right now my twitter widget is having an iframe because of which I couldnt override its css properties.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do about it. It is in an iframe for security reasons so you can not mess with it and click on it without the user knowing.